# Can you transfer attributes from one class instance to another without using inheritance?

Tags: python, class

I'm building a Tkinter app and it is currently all one big class. I'm trying to split it into smaller pieces to make it easier to work on. The problem is some of the smaller pieces contain elements that are referenced elsewhere in the larger app.

editing to add more code:

OK so say I am using `init_library` to make a big complicated frame which then becomes `self.library`.

```
class GUI:
  def __init__(self):
    self.root = tk.Tk()
    self.init_library()
    self.root.mainloop()
    return

  def init_library(self):
    self.library = tk.Frame(self.root)
    [...]
    self.library_var = tk.StringVar("HEY")
    self.library_label = tk.Label(self.library, textvariable=self.library_var)
    [...]

  def action(self, new_text):
    [...]
    self.library_var.set(new_text)
    [...]
```

So assume that `init_library` is large and I would like to put it in a different file to make life easier. Now instead of a class function, I just instantiate `LibraryClass`.

```
from pieces import LibraryClass

class App:
  def __init__(self):
    self.root = tk.Tk()
    self.library = LibraryClass()
    self.root.mainloop()
    return
```

The problem is `library_var` is now a child of `self.library` instead of `App`. So we would have to change `action`.

```
  def action(self, new_text):
    [...]
    self.library.library_var.set(new_text)
    [...]
```

Is there a way to directly assign the `LibraryClass` functions and attributes of `self.library` to `App`?

(I know it seems like a small thing but it would really make my life easier)

Comment: I'm confused. Is big_label a global? Is it an instance attribute? If you can add code examples I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Where is LibraryClass?